# Delete Pwinty Order

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with Pwinty API which create an order and take the photos for print them. I am Stuck in the deletion of Pwinty Photos API Order. Is there any way to delete Pwinty Order

Comment: I think you'd do better asking them directly. There's [cancel](https://pwinty.com/api/#orders-cancel) if that's what you meant, or you could try a DELETE request to [the GET endpoint](https://pwinty.com/api/#orders-get) but there's no guarantee that would work.

Comment: I sent a mail on their support email address but still they didn't reply yet

Comment: We can only change the status of Order.. and if i want to delete all photos then their is no option except you can remove one by one photo
[Delete Single Photo](https://pwinty.com/api/#photos-delete)